# Not able to install Ubuntu on new system

Tags: installation, boot, configuration

I have here a system with

- Asrock Z77 Extrem 4
- Intel 3570K
- Nvidia GTX 570
- OCZ Vertex 2 SSD

I burned the newest Ubuntu 12.10 x64 Image and started to boot from the cd.
The menu is there, but after selecting installation there is just a black screen.

Is this because Im using a Z77 chipset? Maybe I just have to change the boot option, but I have no idea how and what to edit there. Some help? Thank you

Edit: Somebody gave me openSuse 12.2 just to see what is happening, and with the newest suse Im able to go through the install menue and start the installation. Whatever, unfortunately I would like to use ubuntu :) So the question is still there: why and how to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was because of the sata connector on the mainboard.

The mainboard got 4x SATA3 connectors. But these are not equal. If we look into the manual (http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77%20Extreme4/?cat=Manual) there we can see:

> 2 x SATA3 6.0 Gb/s connectors by **Intel® Z77**, support RAID (RAID 0,
>   RAID 1, RAID 5, RAID 10, Intel Rapid Storage and Intel Smart Response
>   Technology), NCQ, AHCI and Hot Plug functions
>
> 2 x SATA3 6.0 Gb/s connectors by **ASMedia ASM1061**, support NCQ, AHCI
>   and “Hot Plug” functions (SATA3_A1 connector is shared with eSATA3
>   port)

I was using two devices on ASMedia ASM1061 and I think Ubuntu dont have any drivers for the ASMedia SATA connector. So after I connected everything to the Intel connector -> no more crashes or black screen during the installation. This is interesting. Wondering why Ubuntu is not able to ignore the devices on the ASMedia connector. Even if I would connect a HDD to the ASMedia that I wont use for the installation for Ubuntu -> crash.

Whatever, I hope this can help for people with the same problem with newer asrock boards. You just should not use the the two connectors

- SATA3 Connectors (SATA3_A0_A1, Gray)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's not limited to the ASRock motherboards but to (at least) that ASM1061 chipset.

I've recently installed a SY-PEX40039 PCIe SATA card (ASM1061 chipset.)

Moving the disk from the add-on PCIe controller to the onboard AMD SB950 of my M5A97 EVO mobo, it boots fine.

I stumbled on this post:

- [Can I prevent an IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE command to a specific device at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230396/can-i-prevent-an-identify-packet-device-command-to-a-specific-device-at-boot)

It states that the culprit is the DVD drive... So I tested this... disconnected my DVD drive, leaving only the hard drive containing the Ubuntu install and it boots fine (fast too! :)

My problem is solved. I just have to move that drive to an onboard one and vice-versa with a hard disk on the onboard ports.