# Ubuntu 18.04 boot process stops at "ATA11: failed to resume link"

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I've been using suggestions from Ask Ubuntu already.

I've managed to disable the video driver using `disablemodules=nouveau`. So I already changed the ISO-file. 
I installed new firmware in my BIOS, reason was TSC-Deadline.

After that the boot starts, but after approximately the length of a command text screen the procedure stops at

```
ATA11: failed to resume link
```

I've no idea what to do.

How can I save the log seen?

What does ATA11 mean?

The computer is stable running Windows 10 64-bit Pro. Since it is without graphics (XEON E3) a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960.

Since I don't have a running Linux installation, I am restricted to Windows tools.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its little unclear what exact problem you have. What your configuration? How exactly did you install Ubuntu? From Graphical Live CD? Alternate CD? Netboot?
Whats wrong with nouveau?

Comment: Configuration is an INTEL XEON E3 with 15GB Main-Memory and SSD harddrive. Video is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960. Monitor is connected via minidisplayport.

Comment: I downloaded the iso file and put it to a USB-stick (rufus). Boot starts, but I never reached GUI or at least a command shell.

Comment: noveau produced a error message. So I found the hint to disable it to go with VESA.

Comment: So, you cant initiate installation, do i get it right?

Comment: command from grub.cfg: linux /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper disablemodules=nouveau splash ---

Comment: Did you tried non-graphical installer?

Comment: no idea how can I select between these? Which one shall I use? ATA11 sounds not like a graphical problem.

Comment: If you want say Ubuntu 18.04 you need installer for 18.04
ATA11 is. from googling, related to harddrive but doesn't seems like real problem. If your harddrive controller doesnt run in legacy IDE mode you should not bother about it.

Comment: so ATA11 is needed for installing. Right? My harddsik controller is running in AHCI mode. Motherboard is ASROCK ASRock Z97 Extreme6 BIOS 2.8 (current)

Comment: I truly believe that ATA warning is not culprit of your problem.

Comment: Ata11 is not what I call warning, it is the end. Only hardware rest helps. So what shall I do?

Comment: If you believe its problem then its may mean that your harddrive controller lost connection to drive which indicated hardware failure. But you say Windows is working totally fine on same hardware?
Thing is what if actual failure is loading graphical driver then you may see message which was barfed by kernel BEFORE actual fail happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you think problem is with graphical drivers i can recommend you to try "non-graphical" installation which not much harder. Do you wish get it try?
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Optimal way is using netboot installer, which pulls everything from internet (and gives you freshest software).

For 18.04 right link is http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/

You should select arch your hardware corresponding too - amd64 for 64 bit, i386 for 32 bit.

Which actual "flavor" (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc) is installed is depends on which Desktop Enviroment you will choose during installation.

Comment: i read the install manual. 
I down loaded [link] /ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot the files mini.iso and boot.img.gz. These were put to an usb-stick by rufus means. the .gz was ungzipped. I ended up with an error message: 'Failed to open \efi\boot\grubx64.efi' ' Failed to load image \efi\boot\grubx64.efi' 'start_image returned not found'; so, finally, no progress at all

Comment: Oh, you right, i'm sorry. netboot cd's dont support EFi for some reason.
Can you try "server" cd? this one SHOULD support EFI http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/release/
One you need is http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/release/ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso i think.

Comment: I took the second one. I'll reached the first selection menu. I choose install server. [33.829816] ata10.00: exception Emask 0x52 ... [33.829918 ata10.00: failed command: Identity packet device .. [33.830006] ata10.00: status: {DRDY}
--> so no success!
Hint I use a m2 SSD hope this is not a problem.

Comment: Do you have optical drive in your system, DVD or BD?

Comment: two optical drives one regular one burning

Comment: From that i see from googleing "failed command: Identity packet device" error is usually associated with problems with optical drives and controller lockups to which drives attached. As for DRDY "this error can be caused by anything from a bad SATA cable to a kernel/chipset problem" and indicates general problem accessing dive.
This questin seems to be related - https://askubuntu.com/questions/230396/can-i-prevent-an-identify-packet-device-command-to-a-specific-device-at-boot